# What are Skyrmion bubbles?

Tags: spin-models, bubbles, quasiparticles, skyrmion

what exactly is the difference between a skyrmion and a skyrmion bubble? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a reference with some more details?

Comment: I do, i mean skyrmion bubbles as in Ref https://science.sciencemag.org/content/349/6245/283